# Bootstrap centers the table

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am  new to twitter bootstrap 3.

The problem is the following bootstrap code always Centers the table:

[image]

I tried to find a class which may  make table so on the left side of page but so far no luck.

Is there such a class and why table show on center?

```
<div id="registerdiv3" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 ">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="regPageTitle">User Registration </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" Text="Register" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" CssClass="lblMessage" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there is something not in the code that you have provided that is causing the table to center. Bootstrap does not center tables by default, and just plugging your code into jsfiddle with bootstrap CSS applied doesn't show anything that is centering the table. Is this inside a larger parent container that has centered content?

Comment: So you do not see any issue from the code above?

Comment: Correct, there must be something else that is causing the table to be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force `registerdiv3` not to center the table.

```
#registerdiv3 table {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Not sure if you need important, but check also without.

Before the above solution, look at the definition of `#registerdiv3` if it contains `margin: 0 auto`, that might be the cause.

Also  it will be helpful for you to right click the on the element in your browser and click inspect element and see which class is causing it.